# mySQL Count subquery super slow with not so much records

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I have a huge UNIONed query, which consists of 13 query like this one below with different category_id-s. These run on two servers:

- The first on normal ssd vps has 18000+ records in products, 19000+ in users
- The second is cloud based (digitalocean,linode) has 3000+ records in products, 13000+ in users. (important stuff, 1 user has 2200+ products)

Both tables (i believe) are indexed properly, settings are almost the default mySQL 5.6 settings

The whole query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS mylist.* FROM 
(
   MAIN SELECT
   UNION SUBCATEGORIES SELECT ... WHERE (COUNT)
   UNION SUBCATEGORIES SELECT ... WHERE (COUNT)
   x13
) mylist
ORDER ...
```

one of the subcategory selects looks like this:

```
SELECT products.*
  FROM
    products
    LEFT JOIN
    users ON (products.user_id = users.id)
  WHERE
    products.lang = 'en'
    AND
    products.category_id IN (61, 63, 154, 155, 64, 65, 156, 66, 67, 68, 157, 195, 69, 70, 158, 170, 171, 203, 204, 205)
    AND
    products.deleted = 0
    AND
    products.public = 1
    AND
    users.banned = 0
    AND
    users.deleted = 0
    AND
    users.active = 1
    AND
    users.type = 'company'

    AND
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM products AS products2
      WHERE
        products2.user_id = products.user_id
        AND
        products2.lang = products.lang
        AND
        products2.category_id IN (61, 63, 154, 155, 64, 65, 156, 66, 67, 68, 157, 195, 69, 70, 158, 170, 171, 203, 204, 205)
        AND
        products2.deleted = 0
        AND
        products2.public = 1
        AND
        products2.created >= products.created
    ) <= 25
  ORDER BY        
    products.created DESC
```

The whole QUERY takes 1-2sec on first server, 14-18sec on second server.

Its obvious that it's because the one user, who has 2200+ products and its also obvious that the problem is generated because of subquery count runs on multiplied rows multiplied times, but I don't truly understand it, because this user has products in a lot of categories but none of the other query parts are that slow. Also the most funny part, that the user is 'person' type, so his products doesn't even included in this query part...
This part takes up to 10 seconds to run.

Also I don't really see, how I could optimize and refactor this query to avoid later slow queries if other users reach this many products.

EDIT 1: Temporary table is not an option, because in mySQL temporary table cannot be referenced in more than one query.

EDIT 2: [Explain result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnxNT.jpg)

EDIT 3: I cannot give out any particular data.
However I didn't write the query, a previous developer did, it's a bit hard to rewrite it, especially, because a lot of lists uses it - or some parts of it -, this is one of the main queries.
If you are in a subcategory, only those parts of the subcat filtering query unions are 'generated', which are inside the current category, if you understand what I mean.

The parts consisting of different categories' subcategory filter, and the script is only resulting those products, which the user doesn't have more than 25 in the concrete category or it's subcategories, as you can see in the attached script.

I don't really see a convenient and faster way to rewrite it without having to completely rewrite the core concept. I tried it with temporary table, but in mySQL you cannot reference a temp table more then once. Using views are just as slow as the main one, because every time you reference it, it has to refresh the view, moreover I can't create a sum table, because we need sums in each category's subcategories.

That's the same problem for refactoring with joins, because then the script has to join a sum count in subcategories for each product, it would be just as slow as this one, or maybe slower and I'm also not sure, whether it's even possible to solve this with JOIN.

Comment: show us the EXPLAIN of your query to see if all indexes used

Comment: I've added the explain table

Comment: I am really sure that is not necessary to have so much UNIONS. i think one wars ok. Can you please say whats is the difference between the 13 UNIONS. Is it also possible that you can give me a Dump with some sample data and the hole query then i will rewrite it for you

Comment: I've added a reply to your comment in EDIT3.